# How to prove this topological lemma?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I am stuck trying to prove some result from topology. It is fairly complicated to state it here, but I realized that I could prove it, if I manage to show the following Lemma.

Suppose $X$ is a normal space (if necessary, we can even assume perfectly normal). Suppose $A$ is a closed subspace of $X$ and $B$ is a closed subspace of $A$, so
$$ B \subseteq A \subseteq X. $$
Furthermore, suppose there is some other space $C \subseteq X$, for which we know that $C \cap A = \emptyset$ and $\overline{C} \cap A \subseteq B$. Can we find an open neighborhood $W$ of $C$ for which $\overline{W} \cap A \subseteq B$?

If we can, how can we prove its existence? If not, could you please provide a counterexample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true if $X$ is merely normal (even under the Hausdorff condition).  A counterexample is the [Tychonoff Plank](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000078) $X=[0,\omega_1]\times [0,\omega]$, with the product of the order topologies.  Let $A=[0,\omega_1]\times \{\omega\} $, $B=\{(\omega_1,\omega)\}$, and $C=\{\omega_1\}\times [0,\omega)$.

Then every neighborhood $W$ of $C$ has $W\supseteq  [\alpha,\omega_1]\times [0,\omega)$ for some countable ordinal $\alpha<\omega_1$, so $\overline{W}\cap A\supseteq [\alpha,\omega_1]\times \{\omega\}$.

On the other hand, if $X$ is [completely normal](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P14) (i.e., "hereditarily normal"), then you can indeed find such a $W$.  By normality of $X\backslash B$, since $\overline{C}\backslash B$ and $A\backslash B$ are (relatively) closed and disjoint, there is a (relatively) open set $W\subset X\backslash B$ with $C\subseteq \overline{C}\backslash B\subseteq W$ and $(\overline{W}\backslash B)\cap (A\backslash B)=\emptyset$, whereby $\overline{W}\cap A\subseteq B$.  Since $B$ is closed, $W$ is in fact open in $X$ as well, and is thus the desired set.

Note that [complete normality is weaker than perfect normality.](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000156)

##### Remark.

In fact, a converse is true: your lemma is equivalent the property that $X$ is completely normal.  To see this, suppose your lemma is true for a space $X$, and let $Y\subseteq X$.  Then let $C,A_1\subset Y$ be (relatively) closed and disjoint.  Let $A=\overline{A_1}$, where the closure is taken with respect to $X$, and let $B=A\cap \overline{C}$.  Then $B\subseteq A$ are closed, and $\overline{C}\cap A\subseteq B$ and $C\cap A=\emptyset$, so $A$, $B$, and $C$ satisfy the assumptions of the lemma.

Then the resulting $W$ satisfies $W\cap Y\supseteq C$ and $\overline{W}\cap Y \cap A_1=\emptyset$ (since $\overline{W}\cap A_1\subseteq \overline{W}\cap A\subseteq B$, and $B\cap Y=\emptyset$), and since $A_1$ and $C$ were arbitrary closed subsets of $Y$, $Y$ is normal.  Since this holds for all subsets $Y\subseteq X$, $X$ is completely normal.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is an awesome answer and exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Jesus I goofed slightly on the original version of the answer, since $C$ is not assumed to be relatively closed in $X\backslash B$. Nonetheless, the original argument given still essentially works, I modified it accordingly so its correct now.